# Ad-Hoc wireless network in C#

Tags: c#, adhoc

I would like to auto-create an ad-hoc wireless network from my laptop.
I use windows XP SP3 and I want to do it using C#.

I have seen some libraries for mobile, but I havent found something regrading PC.
Is there an API to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Despite mentioning C# multiple times, I'm still not clear on how this is programming related?

Comment: I want to write a C# application that autocreates the ad-hoc network, giving it a constant SSID and contant IP address

Comment: And there's a reason you can't just use the built-in operating system tools to do this?  Are you deleting your ad-hoc network on a regular basis or something?

Comment: I am not familiar with these tools. I am not deleting the network on regular base, but I dont want the user to define the ad-hoc manullay. I want the C# application to do it

Comment: Must admit, sounds awfully like a malicious use of ad-hoc functionality...

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old thread, but the response around here to networking in C# seems typically very negative.  His questions is straight forward: Have his c# app create an ad-hoc network with which it can communicate with other devices.  Sure it could be malicious . . . but what do you people care?

Answer (score 0):

Ad-hoc network are usually used in *Ubiquitous Computing* (smart homes). For a laptop, it depends what you'd like to connect to, as ad-hoc usually work with many devices you control.

May be you mean connecting to whatever network you can, in which case it's more on the OS-level.

Comment: Thank for your response. I want to create an ad-hoc so other computers can connect to my computer. I dont want to connect to other networks, just create my own ad-hoc wireless network

Comment: On PC there is no need for a ad-hoc network. A Wifi network would do fine. See: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx

Comment: I know how to do that, but i want to write a C# application that does it

Comment: That's pretty much going to the driver level which, to my knowledge, is not supported on Windows. I say that because people who make softwares that process the Wifi at low level only do it on Linux with success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to setup one machine on the network as a wireless server and forgo Ad Hoc, then the Managed Wifi API on codeplex looks very promising.  It is in C# and works on XP SP3 and higher (and a little bit on SP2, fyi).  http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/

It uses the Native Wifi API from Microsoft.  The Native Wifi API requires you to have a server machine which will hand out private IPs to other devices that connect to the network you create.  In Native Wifi you would want StandAlone mode ICS in order to create your network (if you want internet access on your network use full ICS then).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815252(v=vs.85).aspx

Use the Native Wifi as just a reference though, Managed Wifi API is what you will want for C#.

Answer (score -1):

I'm interested in this too actually.  I think this could be useful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705973(v=vs.85).aspx

Unfortunately, this is only available for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 I believe.
I don't know any c#, but if I did, it'd probably make sense.  If you find any insight, please contact me, I'd also like to learn how to do this as well.